# Clone object with all entire entities in PHP

Tags: php, object, clone, circular-reference

**How to `clone` object in PHP with all entire data?**

So, to clarify: "with all entire data" means that I need any objects inside an instance will be really copied. For example, if you have:

```
class Bar 
{
    public $indicator;
    public function __construct($x)
    {
        $this->indicator = $x;
    }
}
class Foo 
{
    protected $prop;
    public function __construct(Bar $prop) 
    {
        $this->prop = $prop;
    }

    public function getProp()
    {
        return $this->prop;
    }
}

$objX = new Foo(new Bar('one'));
$objY = clone $objX;
$objY->getProp()->indicator = 'two';

//two, since cloned object still tracks references inside it:
echo $objX->getProp()->indicator;
```

The fiddle for code above you can find [here](http://3v4l.org/Ll2b8).

**And it's fine..**

Because standard [`__clone()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) will copy only main object itself:

> When an object is cloned, PHP 5 will perform a shallow copy of all of
>   the object's properties. Any properties that are references to other
>   variables, will remain references.

So it will not track all entities inside as it will be then extremely slow. But now, I need to do that.

The use case is: when I am testing my code, I am providing values storage for callable matcher for phpunit. That storage, however, is a plain map between method name, arguments values and resulted value. All is fine unless I need to use same map value twice - because at the next iteration it might be modified by tested code. And that is a problem.

**Naive approach**

So far, I did this:

```
public static function cloneArrayContainer(array $data)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (is_object($value)) {
            $result[$key] = self::cloneObjectContainer($value);
        } else if (is_array($value)) {
            $result[$key] = self::cloneArrayContainer($value);
        } else {
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

public static function cloneObjectContainer($object)
{
    $result     = clone $object;
    $reflection = new \ReflectionObject($object);
    foreach ($reflection->getProperties() as $property) {
        $property->setAccessible(true);
        $value = $property->getValue($result);
        if (is_object($value)) {
            $property->setValue($result, self::cloneObjectContainer($value));
        } elseif (is_array($value)) {
            $property->setValue($result, self::cloneArrayContainer($value));
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

in one of stub helpers. But it failed on circular references (obviously), which, unfortunately, can not be avoided in my case as they are valid (and demanded by business-logic) objects for my application.

**Any ideas?**

I tried also [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize) / [`serialize()`](http://php.net/serialize) - which failed, and, besides, I may have callables/resources inside my objects, thus, an approach doesn't fit my case. Currently, I am thinking of reconsidering the structure itself (of tests, I mean) - but that would be a last thing, which means that cloning approach failed.

Comment: I thought you could accomplish that by unserializing/serializing, but you already tried... now I'm curious.

Comment: You can accomplish what you are looking for with the `__sleep()` and `__wakeup()` in conjunction with  `unserialize()` /  `serialize()`

Comment: As it is for testing purposes, I am not intended to change my business code just for that. But currently, I'm thinking of that

Comment: could you show samle of data with serialize / unserialize what is wrong there? some objects couldn't be serialized I think :-)  for examle : `$ch = mysql_connect()` you can't really expect that you can pass and store serialized object, and use it when unserialased... etc... so show us please exact data types you can't serialize?

Comment: No, I can not. It's a more or less production data (so it can not be plain-copied due to security reasons) - to reproduce which I will need to copy objects with 7-8 levels of dependencies & references. Hm.. not to say I can not. But too lazy, and I know why that failed - there are stream resources inside and some callbacks too.